# Monogame Sprite Class

Tags: c#, class, monogame

Im working on a level editor in monogame for my engine.

I want to make a class where i can call a simple function and it will draw a sprite.

This is the function i want to call - and as you may know you have to be able to load and unload content and use the draw method.

**Question**: How would I make this be able to use those so that all I have to do is call this function and it works?

Here is the function:

```
public static void DrawSprite(Texture2D Texture, string Path, Vector2 Position, Color Color)
{

}
```

Comment: What do you wanna do with your path parameter?

Comment: That is the path of the sprite in the project folder

Comment: So when i do Texture.loadcontent thats the path

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to leave the drawing to a single static method then you would be restricting what you are able to draw. I suggest creating an interface and do some abstraction.

**Interface**

```
public interface IGameObject
{
    void Update(GameTime gameTime);
    void Draw();
}
```

**Utility Class**

```
public sealed class GameUtility
{
    private static GameUtility instance = null;
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();
    
    public ContentManager ContentManager { get; private set; }
    
    public SpriteBatch SpriteBatch { get; private set; }
    
    public static GameUtility Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new GameUtility();
                }
                
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void SetContentManager(ContentManager contentManager)
    {
        this.ContentManager = contentManager;
    }
    
    public void SetSpriteBatch(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        this.SpriteBatch = spriteBatch;
    }
    
    public GameUtility(ContentManager contentManager, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        this.contentManager = contentManager;
        this.spriteBatch = spriteBatch;
    }
}
```

**Game Objects**

```
public class Hero : IGameObject
{
    private Texture2D texture;
    private Vector2 position;
    private Color color;
    
    public Hero(string path)
    {
        texture = GameUtility.Instance.ContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(path);
    }
    
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Do game update logic
    }
    
    public void Draw()
    {
        GameUtility.Instance.SpriteBatch.Begin();
        
        GameUtility.Instance.SpriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, color);
        
        GameUtility.Instance.SpriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```

**Game Class**

Initialize the GameUtility

```
GameUtility.Instance.SetContentManager(contentManager);
GameUtility.Instance.SetSpriteBatch(spriteBatch);
```

Create the game objects

```
gameObects = new List<IGameObject>();

gameObjects.Add(new Hero("some path"));
```

Utilize the interface

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
 
    foreach (IGameObject gameObject in gameObjects)
    {
        gameObject.Draw();
    }
 
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

The beauty of this approach is you can perform different drawings based on your needs. For example, you could use a `Rectangle` instead of `Vector2` based on different scenarios. You can also draw a sprite font or something else.

For unloading content, there is only one option which is

```
GameUtility.Instance.ContentManager.Unload();
```

You better unload content during your transition to the next level as calling `ContentManager.Unload()` will dispose all resources. As to why it disposes everything in one go, I don't really understand but that is the design.

Hope this answer give you some insight. I would not suggest creating this `public static void DrawSprite`.